# Replacing \" with " in a string (C#)

Tags: c#, json, string, replace, .net-4.5

I have a JSON looking like this

```
"{\"jquery\": [[0, 1, \"call\", [\"body\"]] etc
```

This is obviously wrong and I want to replace the \" parts with " to get the formatting correct.

I've tried so many things.. "\\"", "\"", System.Environment.Newline, I can't get anything to work in String.Replace..

Comment: Where do you see the `\"`? If in the debugger, this is just how it represents the `"` visually.

Comment: Do you really have the `\\` in your strings or are you just seeing them in a tool (debugger) ?

Comment: The best way is to output to console or a textbox.

Comment: Yes, it's in the debugger. I'm inspecing a string and that's the formatting I get. But if this is correct, then maybe my problem is an entirely other matter.

Comment: I suspect it is indeed somewhere else. The debugger will show you embedded double quotes as `\"`, so if you are having issues, you need to look elsewhere. Post the actual error messages you are getting.

Comment: No error messages, but I will continue to look. Thanks for your time. My problem might be with the JavaScripSerializer, but that is outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused..

If you have a string like so, defined somewhere in you C# project:

```
String str = "Foo is \"bar is\" Baz!";
```

It will show the same way in the debugger when you view it. The escape character `\` is saying, don't end my string here, this `"` is part of the string.

If you put the following line,

```
Console.Write(str);
```

You should see this output.

```
Foo is "bar is" Baz!
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly right. I've been coding for 10 hours so maybe I should return to this problem tomorrow. Sorry to waste everyones time.

Comment: @BlackOdd By the way, it is possible to change the way the debugger shows the string in a Watch window [by appending `,nq` to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e514eeby.aspx) the string expression. With `,nq` the backslashes (escape sequences) won't be shown.

Comment: Cool trick :) But I think I'll stick to the default behavior to avoid confusion in the future. To give everyone some closure I figured out my problem, and it was entirely unrelated to this issue. I uploaded the wrong values with a webclient as a POST method and the designated service just went bonkers and formatted the JSON entirely wrong. Thanks all.